# Do some edits not show up in the revision history?

Tags: support, edits, revisions-list, grace-period

I made a comment to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15107214/passing-parameter-to-boost-thread#15107289) when it was just a couple minutes old. A few minutes later it had changed (at least I am *very, very* sure about that), invalidating my comment. The odd thing is that no "edited X mins ago" text shows up, I can see no revision history. Is there a timeframe in which edits just override the post with the old version not showing up as earlier revision?

Comment: There is a 5 minute grace period.